# always freeze at httpwebresponse and cannot do anything

Tags: c#, android, httpwebresponse

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/login.php?id=boonjye91") as HttpWebRequest;

HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
response.Close();
// Read the response
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();

// This just shows the server's response, but you'll probably want to do other things
Toast.MakeText(this, responseText, ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

when I run the breakpoint. I explored that it's stuck & freeze at the webresponse.
why ?

Comment: arent u getting any response or exception while running the program..?

Answer (score 0):

try this to run in Asyntask and get your result what you need in onPostExecute() methods.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html